# Managing a group of docker containers without the sweat

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using a bash script to spin up a virtual network with two docker containers on it. This feels prehistoric. Is there some tool that can spin such an ensemble up and down & show its current status, or does one have to take care of that on their own?

In case `docker-compose`, it is unclear from docker documentation whether docker-compose is self-contained or tied to swarm, and an authoritative example of a compose definition file, with commands for starting and stopping the ensemble would be very helpful.

E.g. here is what a bash script would do to define/start an application of two interrelated containers, needless to say this script does not help with managing its lifecycle beyond just starting it up once.

```
docker network create --driver bridge FooAppNet
docker run --rm --net=FooAppNet --name=component1 -p 9000:9000 component1-image
docker run --rm --net=FooAppNet --name=component2 component2-image
```

Also in this example, container `component1` exposes port 9000 to the host, and its contained application has it hardwired in its configuration file, to consume the service of `component2` by its name (following the common docker networking practice relying on [docker networks' internal DNS](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/)).

Comment: Probably best to start with Docker Compose. You can use it independently of Swarm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the example you've given, the following Docker Compose file would give you what you want:

```
component1:
  image: component1-image
  net: FooAppNet
  container_name: component1
  ports:
    - "9000:9000"
component2:
  image: component2-image
  net: FooAppNet
  container_name: component2
```

If you store this in a `docker-compose.yml` file and then run `docker-compose up -d` it will create/start/restart your containers and assign them to your `FooAppNet` network.

The `-d` flag runs the containers in detached mode and prevents the logging output being printed to your terminal window when you start the containers. You can still get their log via `docker logs -f ...` like with any other container.

You can then use `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose restart` etc to control the ensemble's lifecycle. As an aside, [using variables](http://blog.arungupta.me/docker-bridge-overlay-network-compose-variable-substitution/) can spice up the definition file towards greater flexibility.

See in the comments below about using the network automatically spun up by docker compose.

Comment: Separately running `docker network create --driver bridge` makes it all, well, not self-contained. (pun intended). Also posted about the latter key part as [a separate question now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708873/how-do-you-define-a-network-in-a-version-2-docker-compose-definition-file).

Comment: For enjoying the default network created for the project by compose, need to also remove the `net:` lines above from the configuration. In short, see here ― https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR ― see the beginning section of https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ for the solution. It walks you through the entire necessary configuration. Works nicely, and need to master the various `docker-compose` command-line options to be productive with it.